# How to use installed plugin in a java project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have created one java project with 'project_p' with three packages a, b and c.

In package 'a', I have class 'A', method 'action' which prints: "inside class A". In package b, class B, method 'boxing' which prints: "inside class B". In package 'c', class 'C', method 'catching' - this prints: "inside class C" and also calls 'action' and 'boxing'. There is no main method in any class.

```
project_p
   |
   src
     |
     |
      -> a --> class A --> method action   --> System.out.println("inside class A.");
     |
     |
      -> b --> class B --> method boxing   --> System.out.println("inside class B."); 
     |
     |
      -> c --> class C --> method catching --> System.out.println("inside class C."); 
                                               A aobj = new A();
                                               aobj.action();
                                               B.boxing();
```

Then, I created a jar of 'project_p' with all the three packages.
Used that jar to create a plugin 'project_plugin', created the feature 'project_plugin_feature' and update site 'project_plugin_site' for the plugin.
Then installed that plugin to Eclipse using Help --> Install new software.

Now, I have created another java project 'project_plugin_usage' with one package 'abc', class ABC.  There is one main method inside class ABC.

My question is - How can I use that installed plugin in the project 'project_plugin_usage' so that I could call method 'action', 'boxing', and 'catching' in the main method of 'project_plugin_usage'?

Comment: You can't use plug-in code in a plain Java project - only another plug-in.

Comment: @greg-449 Do you mean that I can not use/import plugin in plain java project?

Comment: That is correct. Code in plug-ins can only be used by other plug-ins.

Comment: @greg-449 Please help me to know how can I use one plugin in another plugin project? By importing or how? Any link that you may share with me.

Answer (score 0):

A plain Java project cannot use code in a plug-in. Only another plug-in can access the code.

For plug-ins: the plug-in providing the code must declare the packages that it makes available in a `Export-Package` statement in its MANIFEST.MF.

For example:

```
Export-Package: greg.music.core.autoclose,
 greg.music.core.bool
```

exports two packages.

If the plug-in wants to export packages from a jar included in the plug-in it must include the jar in the `Bundle-ClassPath` in the MANIFEST.MF

The plug-in which wants to use the packages must add the source plug-in to the `Require-Bundle` statement in its MANIFEST.MF

```
Require-Bundle: pluginid
```